# Adding border around the wordpress pagination numbers?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, pagination

How to add the border around the wordpress pagination starting from the first number and ends to the final number in the pagination.
Wordpress pagination return the following pagination structure

```
<a class="prev page-numbers"></a>
<a class="page-numbers">1</a>
<a class="page-numbers">2</a>
<span class="page-numbers current">3</span>
<a class="page-numbers">4</a>
<a class="next page-numbers"></a>
```

i tried to add the div after .prev and before .next through jquery but it also adds the closing div then thy are not coming in the wrapper.

Any other method????

Answer (score 0):

Use Tw Pagination

[Tw Pagination](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tw-pagination/installation/)

Simple and flexible pagination